# W3.css How to make in one line?

Tags: html, font-awesome, w3.css

I have few elements, 2 `i` and 1 `input`.
The layout I using `w3-col` from a frameworks called [w3.css](http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css), and a font icon library called [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io).
Since `s7` + `s5` = `s12`, why my elements still drop to the new row?
The 3 elements in div `s5` expected should be in the same line.
Hope you guys can help me on this.

```
<div class="w3-row w3-section">
    <div class="w3-col s7">
        <label><b>Apple</b></label>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s5">
        <i id="plus" class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:24px"></i>
        <input id="noOfApple" class="w3-input w3-border-0" type="text" name="noOfApple" value="1" size="3">
        <i id="minus" class="fa fa-minus" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `display:inline-block`

Comment: can you provide a working example

Comment: Its running fine here http://codepen.io/shivk/pen/apmEMr..then what you want?

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi, you're not including the font awesome library that OP is using, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPKyOe

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi Your link page not found.

Answer (score 1):

[`w3.css`](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_references.asp#input) doesnt currently support "input-group"s. I use the term input groups, because this is the term that [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) uses to refer to what you're looking for. What we can do, is examine the [Bootstrap `input-group`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic) code, and extend `w3.css`'s code to include similarly prefixed versions. Unfortunately, `w3.css` uses the class `w3-input-group` already, so we will use `w3-inline-input-group`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="w3-row w3-section">
    <div class="w3-col s7">
        <label><b>Apple</b></label>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s5 w3-inline-input-group">
        <i id="plus" class="fa fa-plus w3-input-group-addon"></i>
        <input id="noOfApple" class="w3-input w3-border-0" type="text" name="noOfApple" value="1" size="3">
        <i id="minus" class="fa fa-minus w3-input-group-addon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.w3-inline-input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.w3-inline-input-group .w3-input {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.w3-inline-input-group .w3-input:focus {
    z-index: 3;
}
.w3-input-group-addon,
.w3-inline-input-group .w3-input {
    display: table-cell;
}
.w3-input-group-addon
{
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.w3-input-group-addon {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yf3rb2ms/4/)**

**NOTE**: JsFiddle doesnt allow inclusion of non-https external files, so please scroll to the BOTTOM of the css pane to find the new/above css

PS. If you havent come too far in your project, and you're going to be working with `form` elements a lot, I would *strongly* suggest looking into the Twitter Bootstrap CSS framework (you can customise an export of the library, to exclude all JS if you want to build all your own stuff, but again, they have a lot of very useful out-of-the-box code that I would recommend). It's a great place to start, and is far more widely used that w3.css (at least in terms of jobs asking for a knowledge of it)

Answer (score 0):

Markup you had written is correct. 
Your own code might be **overwriting s7 and s5** class property `float: left`;

If you found it's overwriting then correct this.

Also add this style for input component

```
`.s5 {
  position: relative;

}

.s5 input {
   padding: 8px 15px;
}
.s5 i {
  z-index: 1; 
}
.s5 #plus { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px
}
.s5 #minus { 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 8px
}`
```

Here is live example of your code :)

http://codepen.io/kaushik/pen/JERMwg

Comment: You are not including the FontAwesome library that OP is using http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPKyOe

Comment: @haxxxton Yes! When you run the code, you will notice the input and - drop to new line. That what I mean.

Comment: You need to write style for this component add below style in your css file.

s5 {
  position: relative;
  
}

.s5 input {
   padding: 8px 15px;
}
.s5 i {
  z-index: 1; 
}
.s5 #plus { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px
}
.s5 #minus { 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 8px
}

now see codepen code may be that's what you wanted.

http://codepen.io/kaushik/pen/JERMwg?editors=0110